# Why does the Java reflection API allow us to access private and protected fields and methods? Doesn't this break the purpose of access modifiers?

Tags: java, reflection, access-modifiers

We can access private variables through the Java reflection API. So then what is the use of having access modifiers? Also help me to get a better understanding of the real usage of access modifiers (private, public, etc.) in real-world applications.

Comment: Reflection is not used for general development, it has very specific use cases, such as for writing tools and frameworks.  Access modifiers are there to help organise your code, for example to hide implementation details, to reduce the exposed area of a _public_ API.

Comment: I think you can also turn this off with a SecurityManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still protects private variables from beeing used wrong by developers. If someone uses reflection to access private variables he (hopefuly) knows what he is doing.

Also most frameworks won't access the variable directly, but instead will look for the getter and setter of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

That "access of private" fields via reflection is not going to be supported for a very long time, eventually it will disappear. With most recent java versions, you already get warnings when you try to access things in a reflective way (like `private` and `protected`). In future versions, that might be gone entirely. The `JVM` becomes more and more encapsulated and restricted in each version, via project `jigsaw`.

And newer APIs in `java`, like `MethodHandles`, that can create/access `private` members via `privateLookupIn` will fail if you are not within proper scope. In simpler words - you *can* access private members of some code, like in a `module` that allows/exposes such access, but not everywhere. In a way, this is a more restrictive API rather than `reflection`. So work to block such usages is on the way, via properly crafted newer APIs.

As to the argument that reflections is used by libraries - that is true. But rarely a good library will need private access. `Spring`, which is the most famous - does not need that information. It only needs `public` `class` data (like methods that are `public`), `annotations`, etc.